# Using Android Studio, where is compiler error output?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio.  When I try to run my project I get the message:

```
Gradle: 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':AsteroidRunnerMultiplayer:compileDebug'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

It references *compiler error output*, but I can't seem to find that output anywhere.  Where is it so I can figure out why my project fails to build?

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is deactivate the external build. To do so click on "compiler settings icon" in the "Messages Make" panel that appears when you have an error. You can also open the compiler settings by going to File -> Settings -> Compiler.

[image]

Uncheck "Use External build"

[image]

And you will see the errors in the console

EDIT: After returning to "internal build" again you may get some errors, you can solve them this way: [Android Studio: disabling "External build" to display error output create duplicate class errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108393/android-studio-disabling-external-build-to-display-error-output-create-duplic/17220509#17220509)

Comment: Is this still valid ? I don't see these checkboxes in the compiler window and I'm also not seeing the actual errors in the IDE. (I do see them when running gradlew outside the IDE).

Comment: @ddewaele Yes, is still there. I've edited my answer so you can find it under settings too.

Comment: @ddewaele Ok, I've just noticed an update in Android Studio and that box dissapeared. Going to search how to workaround this.

Comment: It's not there in the latest version. Ridiculous problem anyway.

Comment: What does external build mean? Isn't there any way to see the compiler output without disabling external build?