# Android Studio: disabling "External build" to display error output create duplicate class errors

Tags: android-studio

I am starting my migration from Eclipse to Android Studio, and start playing with new projects on Studio.

My test project was working fine till I got some errors messages.

I had to do some manipulation (https://stackoverflow.com/a/16876993/327402) to enable the error output to display, and found the issue that I fixed.

Unfortunately, after this "workaround" (Why the hell have I to make such things to see my errors?), I found that there was an error message that I cannot fix:

```
error: duplicate class: com.mypackage.name.BuildConfig
error: duplicate class: com.mypackage.name.R
```

I also noticed that I am not the only one to have this issue (see the comment in the SO answer I linked above)

First time, I was able to fix it by enabling "External build" again, but that happened again, because I needed to see the error output and everything is now broken, and I cannot find what happen.

With Eclipse, the R file was easy to find, in the gen folder, but with Android Studio, there are too many files, and I am a little bit lost.

Any idea/suggestion?

Comment: Good question, I've spent one whole day to this and have given up for the time being.

Comment: See my answer, upgrading Android Studio to 0.1.5 fixed everything!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, just to let you know...

A few minutes after I posted my question, Google released an update to Android Studio (0.1.5)
See link: https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/Y9vhvGaHCbh

Tor Norbye kindly answered my question in this community, and I am sharing here

So the workaround I quoted in the OP is no more mandatory.

Enabling again External build after upgrading Android Sudio let me see the real errors ( a library and some Gradle import that I fixed)

So, I consider the Android Studio upgrade as the best answer to this question...

Comment: So we can now see errors within Android Studio even if Use External Build is checked?

Answer (score 3):

I've found a question like this that has some replies here:

[Cannot resolve R.java, duplicate class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17104020/cannot-resolve-r-java-duplicate-class)

You can try this:

- Delete the Build folder generated by Android Studio automatically

Also you can try to Rebuild project by clicking Build->Rebuild project after deleting build folder.

Comment: Unfortunately, this and many other answers has nothing to do with android studio. There is no clean, and there is no gen folder. And where can we find Java Build Path thingy.

Comment: * EDITED * (Misunderstood your comment). Removed Eclipse info from answer, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I also have the same problem, and this is what worked for me.
I first unticked external build from compiler settings. Then when I compiled i get two errors related to R.java, duplicate class.
Then i delete the build folder manually from finder. Then rebuild it from android studio, but still same error.
Then I again go back to compiler preference and tick the external build setting, and it worked fine after that. 
Looks like some bug.

Comment: A variation of this answer worked for me: (1) disabled external build; (2) try to run the project and failed; (3) manually delete the build folder; (4) run the project again. After trying to run it I got the dialog to select either a phone or emulator.

Answer (score 0):

apparently, or at least for me 0.1.5 has a bug and cannot run in external build 
because of some path error you can read about here
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56628

so i switched to internal building, and then i hit the double R symbol bug

after deleting the build path application is compiled without errors but the build folder is not fully rebuilt, I'm missing the R.java file which the internal builder does not make.

i've rebuilt it on the external builder on an unupdated version as a temp workaround while this issues is fixed.

btw if anyone knows how to tell internal gradle to rebuild the build folder please share.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and found a way to solve it (You can do this with Android Studio open):

- Go to you Android Studio projects folder located in c:\users[USERNAME]\AndroidStudioProjects
- Locate your project folder and open it.
- Delete the folder named `build`.
- From here, enter your application name folder, where you can find another `build` folder among with `libs` and `src` folders and a file named `build.gradle`.
- **RENAME** the `build` folder to `build2` or something else.
- Now in Android Studio go to `Build->Rebuild Project`.
- And after the project was rebuilt, open again the folder where the `build2` folder that you renamed is located.
- Delete the new folder named `build` that was created.
- Rename your `build2` folder to `build` again.

Done.